# Powershell won't run macro, but macro runs fine manually

Tags: vba, powershell

This problem has been driving me crazy and can't find a solution anywhere. I have a super simple strip of code in powershell that opens and excel and then runs a macro (named Refresh). The macro is saved to the workbook. The first thing in the macro is to run RefreshAllWorkbooks. As soon as powershell hits that line it errors out: run-time error 1004 Cannot run the macro 'Refreshallworkboooks' the macro may not be available or all macros may be disabled.

When I manually open excel and run that same macro, I get no errors. What can I do to fix this?

I appreciate any help!

```
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
# open file
$FilePath = 'C:\Users\ap1\OneDrive\DailyPerf.xlsm'
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

#make it visible
$excel.Visible = $true

#access the Application object and run a macro 
$app = $excel.Application
$app.Run('Refresh')
```

Comment: Error message and script don’t match? Is it Refresh or refreshallworkbooks ?

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open :
"By default, macros are enabled when opening files programmatically. 
Use the AutomationSecurity property [on the Application object] to set the macro security mode used when opening files programmatically."

Comment: Where is the macro?  In a regular module, or somewhere else?  Is it Private?

Comment: Solved! ThAnks to both of you. Had to do with where macro was being saved. Thanks!